# When Jetpack compose team will create a library or package for us handling with currency on text input? Such as brazilian currency?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I wish there was a package that would handle user input and do some monetary manipulation by itself.
And the package would have some properties such as: local currency, and if we choose brl for example, and type 2536330, the value displayed in the input would be: 25,363.30 and so on...

I been trying differents approachs, and have to write a lot of unecessary code